# Printing in a loop with a count

Tags: java

I am reading a file and printing out the file. What I am doing is counting mismatched parenthesis. The code I have works and counts the braces correctly. But the problem is the  format will only print the count at the front of the line not right behind the braces. I only need the count to print when there is a brace. is there anyway to format the the print statement to the end of the line? Check where my "\n" statements are. I'm wondering if there is one where instead of a linebreak it appends to the the end of a line.

```
                if (brace == '{')
                {
                    count++;
                    System.out.print("\n" + count);
                }
                else if (brace == '}')
                {
                    count = count;
                    System.out.print("\n" + count);
                    count--;
                    if (count < 0)
                    {
                    count = 0;
                    }
                }

            }
                System.out.println(inputLine);
```

Comment: this is a poorly worded question.  What is `brace` and what is your intention on the line `count = count;`?

Comment: Braces are curly braces. The problem is not with the code. I thought the code would only help explain the question. I'm trying to print a number behind each curly brace. and when its unmatched print 0. My code compiles and runs but the number is printed in front of the line because of the loop. I wanted to know if and how i could print the number at the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

This line doesn't do anything, remove it:

```
count = count;
```

To print the count right behind braces, change your print statements to:

```
System.out.print(count + "\n");
```

Comment: Simply use `System.out.println(count);`

Comment: If I do that it prints at the beginning of the line

Comment: Sampson that just prints the count on a line before where I need it

Comment: public class Tester {1
    public static void main(String[] args) {2
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
int price = in.nextInt;
if price < 10
System.out.println("Good price");
System.out.println ("Buy it");
}2
}1
}0
}0

Comment: I need the output to print like this ^^^ @sampson-chen

Comment: Can you include more code, especially where you actually print the braces? Also, add code to your question, not the comments

Answer (score 0):

Place the statement that prints the line of source code:

```
System.out.println(inputLine);
```

at the top, before printing the brace counts. You may also consider using `print` instead of `println` so that the brace count is printed next to it, not on a new line.